# css to make input and textarea looks like simple html text

Tags: html, css

I had form with a lot of `<input>` and `<textarea>`, and I manage to save and retrieve the data with php.
Now I need to make another interface (admin) where I have to retrieve the value not as input/textarea field, but as simple string.

To make it simple I had a thousand codes like this,

```
<div><input type='text' <?php echo "value='".$value1."'";?> ></div>
<div><textarea> <?php echo $value2;?> </textarea></div>
```

On admin, I want it to appear like this code,

```
<div><?php echo $value1;?></div>
<div><?php echo $value2;?></div>
```

I want to keep the `<input>` and `<textarea>` cause I'm too lazy to recode everything, but I need it to looks like there's no input/textarea.

Is there anyway I can retweak the input and textarea css to taking down everything except the value and make it looks like simple html text?

Not only the outline, but this include taking down the focus cursor, height/width limitation, and disabled the editable feature.

I know this is not the best idea, but I don't think I had time to remove all those hundred input/textarea field on admin interface.

UPDATE:
I need to show the overflowed text in textarea which in default is a scrollbar with something like 'Automatic Height textarea'.

Comment: you can remove its`border` and `box-shadow` in css so it will look like a plain text. Also in its `:focus` state

Comment: So you want to change tags? JS will be required: `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea'), function (e) { e.parentNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(e.value)); e.parentNode.removeChild(e); });` (more or less)

Comment: woah, seriously your javascript code work.
Though my question is about css, this comment is the best solution for my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**use follwing css**

```css
input,
textarea {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: text;
}
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="xyz" readonly/>
<br>
<textarea readonly>sasf</textarea>
```

**Edit:**

Add readonly attribute if dont want user to edit any text and also add `cursor:text;` in css if disabled cursor is shown in any browser

Comment: `cursor: default;` will be more appropriate

Comment: yes but generally for text we show cursor to select. But anyways it depends on user choice

Comment: I need to show the overflowed text in textarea. This doesn't seems to give me enough solution due to this overflow-y: hidden

Comment: You wan't the scroll bar or automatic height increasing textarea?

Comment: @user6748005 you know your needs best, have a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: since automatic height is a different case (and might use js), I'll as well mark this as accepted answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input class="nostyle" type='text' value='<?php echo $value1; ?>' readonly />
</div>
<div>
    <textarea readonly><?php echo $value2;?></textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nostyle{
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    outline:none;
    background: #fff;
    cursor:default;
    resize:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `input[type="text"], textarea {all: unset;}`